# ASP.NET MVC 4 Intranet Template - Show Users Full Name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using the Intranet template for MVC 4 under the VS 2012 RC. The top right hand corner shows domain\username, and I want it to show full name instead.

I was able to get this working in _Layout.cshtml. I included the following helper in the body -

```
@helper AccountName()
{       
    using (var context = new System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext(System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType.Domain))
    {
        try
        {
            var principal = System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, User.Identity.Name); 
            @String.Concat(principal.GivenName, " ", principal.Surname) 
        }
        catch { }

    } 
}
```

(I also had to include System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement in the References)

I could then use the helper in the greeting code as follows -

```
 <section id="login">
      Hello, <span class="username">@AccountName()</span>!
 </section>
```

This works ok, but I don't like having the code in the _Layout.cshtml. I tried to put the helper in a seperate file under a Helpers directory, but @AccountName() no longer resolved then. Ideally the code should really be in a straight CS file.

Can anyone suggest a better way to set this up?

Comment: this doesn't work for me. I put that helper at the top of my _layout and it's saying the directory of namespace DirectoryServices is not available.. I have it added in app 'references'... what am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can certainly put the code in a regular C# file, e.g.

```
AccountUtil.AccountName()
```

In that case, you need to include the namespace your helpers are in by placing

```
@using My.App.Helpers  @* Change to your own namespace *@
```

at the top of any view that wants to reference that code.

Alternatively, you can make that namespace available to all views by editing the `web.config` file in the Views directory (*not* the one at the project level)

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <!-- Don't edit out the stuff that's already here! -->
        <add namespace="My.App.Helpers" />  <!-- Add your own namespace here -->
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: One further question - I obviously only want to search Active Directory once, so I've set up a static variable in my helper class to contain the value. Is there a "best practice" in ASP.NET MVC to do this sort of thing?